# "Show code snippet" chevron is underlined

Tags: bug, design, stack-snippets

Links in posts on Meta are given a bottom border:

```
.wmd-preview a, .post-text a, .comment-copy a {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #444;
}
```

This results in the chevron next to "Show code snippet" also being underlined in an ugly way:

> [image: Stack snippet link]

*twitch*

This line in the CSS is meant to remove it:

```
a.snippet-show-link-chevron, a.snippet-show-link-chevron:hover {
  border-bottom: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

... but it doesn't because it is being placed in the CSS *before* the declaration block containing the border and they both have the same specificity of 11. It is only removed on `:hover` thanks to the +10 specificity.

The specificity should be increased using `.post-text a.snippet-show-link-chevron` or the remove border block should be placed *after* the add bottom border block.

Sanity is then restored:

> [image: Fixed!]

---

**Bonus OCD points!** Apply the border to the span instead so it is consistent with regular links:

Regular link:

[Show code snippet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Border applied to span:

> [image: Applied to span]

Comment: @ArunA.S - [Well this is Meta](http://goo.gl/x2rpp4), and it is a [very old joke.](http://goo.gl/ctSpxS)

Comment: @arunA.S how is that related in the slightest?